# Checkbox similar to Email opt-out

Tags: developer-console

How can I create a checkbox similar to Email opt-out which has the same functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Email Opt Out field is a "magic field." While you can create a custom field to emulate this feature in some capacity, this field is special in regards to the API, the Email Opt Out field cannot be directly replicated. In other words, the API for sending an email will not respect a custom field, but will respect the standard field for opting out of email. Again, there's no way to replicate the standard functionality, because it is a special system feature. If you want to avoid sending emails to contacts or leads, you must use the standard field. You can use a Process Builder or Workflow Rule to set or unset the field value, but it must be this field in order to comply with email regulations.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom field of type CheckBox. Update it however you want/need and in every email you are going to send(Process Builder, Apex, Campaign, etc) check its value.